# How do I apply Mixins to all CBVs in a django app?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I want to use the LoginRequiredMixin and a UserPermissionMixin created by myself and apply them to all the views in an app. This is just an example, I might also have mixins that add some context or do other stuff.

I could do it manually, for example this view:

```
class MyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPermissionMixin, CreateView)
```

But, since I have many views and I might have other specific mixins for some views, this gets messy and hard to manage.

One solution that came to mind would be to create new classes for the generic views:

```
class DecoratedCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPermissionMixin, CreateView):
    pass


class DecoratedDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPermissionMixin, DetailView):
    pass


class DecoratedUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPermissionMixin, UpdateView):
    pass


class DecoratedDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPermissionMixin, DeleteView):
    pass
```

and then, use these as my generic views:

```
class MyCreateView(DecoratedCreateView)
```

Is this a good approach? Do I have to add any methods in the classes above or do I just leave them blank and it'll work as expected?
Is there any other way to achieve this, maybe in urls.py ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is good. I've been doing so for some projects with a slight difference:

**myapp/views/generic.py**

```py
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView as BaseCreateView,
    DetailView as BaseDetailView,
    UpdateView as BaseUpdateView,
    DeleteView as BaseDeleteView,
)

__all__ = ['MyappMixin', 'CreateView', 'DetailView', 'UpdateView', 'DeleteView']


class MyappMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserpermissionMixin):
    pass


class CreateView(MyappMixin, BaseCreateView):
    pass


class DetailView(MyappMixin, BaseDetailView):
    pass


class UpdateView(MyappMixin, BaseUpdateView):
    pass


class DeleteView(MyappMixin, BaseDeleteView):
    pass
```

**myapp/views/base.py**

```py
from .generic import CreateView

class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    pass
```

It works fine, without much hassle, and allows you to easily skip the mixin exceptionally if needed.

According to the usecase, another solution might be to use [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/) or [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext).

```py
class MyMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        is_in_myapp = request.resolver_match.app_name == 'myapp'
        if is_in_myapp and not request.user.is_authenticated:
            response = HttpResponse("Permission denied", status=403)
        else:
            response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this Idea saved me 2 hours of manual editing all existing Update and CreateViews instead of changing the imports!